# Debugging GDB itself and signal handling issues

Tags: debugging, gdb, ubuntu-16.04, gnu

I am trying to debug GDB itself and dealing with a Ctrl+C signal problem that is sent from another terminal.

I run GDB to be debugged in **terminal 1** in TUI mode. Right after, I open another **terminal 2** and find the PID number of the GDB that runs on **Terminal 1**. Then attach that process to debug.

In Terminal 1

```
$ build-gdb/gdb/gdb -tui ./build/output.elf -tty=$TTY
```

In Terminal 2

```
$ ps -elf | less
$ sudo gdb -p PID_NUMBER-tty=$TTY -tui
```

The problem is when I hit Ctrl+C to stop GDB in **terminal 1**, GDB runs on **Terminal 2** stops. GDB in **Terminal 1** does not responds to ^C command at all. I tried to use -tty parameter and get the current TTY, but id did not solved the problem. GDB uses readline GNU library, but i should be configure terminal and its input properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
handle SIGINT pass
```

to instruct GDB to pass the signal to the inferior.  See [Signals](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Signals.html) in the GDB manual.  The `nostop` argument could be useful in this situation, too.